# Email : filter out and move to other folder

Tags: macos, email, apple-mail, email-filter

How can I use such a filter that all the emails coming to Mail.app on Mac OS goes to some folder and get removed from inbox?

I get 100+ emails daily from JIRA (as all are not so important, all the notifications are not important for me. Also I need these for future use, incase I need them) and dozens of important emails. I want only important emails under the inbox.

Answer (score 0):

Not a big hack, this options is available in Mail.app itself.

Open Mail's preference window, goto Rules Tab.

[image]

Add a rule as, it will move the mail to some other location. In this case I created a folder on my Mac.:

[image]

[image]